# Why is std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free() not static as well as constexpr?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lock-free, stdatomic

Can anyone tell me whether `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free()` isn't static as well as constexpr? Having it non-static and / or as non-constexpr doesn't make sense for me.

Why wasn't it designed like [C++17's `is_always_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free) in the first place?

Comment: Are you aware of [`is_always_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free)?

Comment: I'm going to throw "alignment" out there.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Do you mean that not all instances are going to be aligned the same way?

Comment: Mike, no, I wasn't aware, but thanks for this hint; it is really helpful for me. But I'm asking myself why there's a decision between is_lock_free() and is_always_lock_free. It can't be because of unaligned atomics, waht others suggested here, since the language defines unaligned accesses to have undefined behaviour anyway.

Answer (score 13):

As explained on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free):

> All atomic types except for std::atomic_flag may be implemented using mutexes or other locking operations, rather than using the lock-free atomic CPU instructions. **Atomic types are also allowed to be sometimes lock-free, e.g. if only aligned memory accesses are naturally atomic on a given architecture, misaligned objects of the same type have to use locks.**
>
> The C++ standard recommends (but does not require) that lock-free atomic operations are also address-free, that is, suitable for communication between processes using shared memory.

As mentioned by multiple others, [`std::is_always_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free) might be what you are really looking for.

---

Edit: To clarify, C++ object types have an alignment value that restricts the addresses of their instances to only certain multiples of powers of two ([`[basic.align]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#basic.align)). These alignment values are implementation-defined for fundamental types, and need not equal the size of the type. They can also be more strict than what the hardware could actually support.

For example, x86 (mostly) supports unaligned accesses. However, you will find most compilers having `alignof(double) == sizeof(double) == 8` for x86, as unaligned accesses have a host of disadvantages (speed, caching, atomicity...).  But e.g. `#pragma pack(1) struct X { char a; double b; };` or `alignas(1) double x;` allows you to have "unaligned" `double`s. So when cppreference talks about "aligned memory accesses", it presumably does so in terms of the natural alignment of the type for the hardware, not using a C++ type in a way that contradicts its alignment requirements (which would be UB).

Here is more information: [What's the actual effect of successful unaligned accesses on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491578/whats-the-actual-effect-of-successful-unaligned-accesses-on-x86)

Please also check out the insightful comments by **@Peter Cordes** below!

Comment: 32-bit x86 is a good example of where you find ABIs with `alignof(double)==4`.  But `std::atomic<double>` still has `alignof() = 8` instead of checking alignment at runtime.  Using a packed struct that under-aligns atomic breaks the ABI and is not supported.  (GCC for 32-bit x86 prefers to give 8-byte objects natural alignment, but struct-packing rules override that and are only based on `alignof(T)`, e.g. on i386 System V.  G++ used to have a bug where `atomic<int64_t>` inside a struct might not be atomic because it just assumed.  GCC (for C not C++) still has this bug!)

Comment: But a correct implementation of C++20 `std::atomic_ref<double>` will either reject under-aligned `double` entirely, or will check alignment at runtime on platforms where it's legal for plain `double` and `int64_t` to be less than naturally aligned.  (Because `atomic_ref<T>` operates on an object that was declared as a plain `T`, and only has a minimum alignment of `alignof(T)` without the opportunity to give it extra alignment.)

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62259 for the now-fixed libstdc++  bug, and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65146 for the still-broken C bug, including a pure ISO C11 testcase that shows tearing of an `_Atomic int64_t` when compiled with current `gcc -m32`.  Anyway, my point is that real compilers don't support under-aligned atomics, and don't do runtime checks (yet?), so **`#pragma pack` or `__attribute__((packed))` will just lead to non-atomicity; objects will still report that they are `lock_free`.**

Comment: But yes, the purpose of `is_lock_free()` is to *allow* implementations to work differently from the way current ones actually do; with runtime checks based on actual alignment to use HW-supported atomic instructions or to use a lock.

Comment: Correction to my earlier comments: in order to use `std::atomic_ref` on a double, you need to make sure it's properly aligned yourself, like `alignas( std::atomic_ref<double>::required_alignment ) double foo`.  Otherwise it's UB, so `atomic_ref` doesn't have to check for alignment or handle under-aligned objects.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref/required_alignment

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`std::is_always_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free)

`is_lock_free` depends on the actual system and can't be determined at compile time.

Relevant explanation:

> Atomic types are also allowed to be sometimes lock-free, e.g. if only
>   aligned memory accesses are naturally atomic on a given architecture,
>   misaligned objects of the same type have to use locks.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<int>::max` depends on the architecture, yet is is static and `constexpr`. I guess there is nothing wrong in the answer, but I dont buy the first part of the reasoning

Comment: Doesn't define the language unaligned accesses to have undefined behaviour anyway so that an evaluation of lock-free-ness or not at runtime would be nonsense?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to decide between aligned and unaligned accesses as the language defines the latter as undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BonitaMontero There is "unaligned in the C++ object alignment" sense and "unaligned in what the hardware likes" sense. Those are not necessarily the same, but in practice they frequently are. The example you show is one such instance where the compiler apparently has the built-in assumption that the two _are_ the same - which only means that `is_lock_free` is pointless _on that compiler_.

Comment: You can be pretty sure that an atomic would have proper alignment if there is a alignment-requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I've got installed Visual Studio 2019 on my Windows-PC and this devenv has also an ARMv8-compiler. ARMv8 allows unaligned accesses, but compare and swaps, locked adds etc. are mandated to be aligned. And also pure load / pure store using `ldp` or `stp` (load-pair or store-pair of 32-bit registers) are only guaranteed to be atomic when they're naturally aligned.

So I wrote a little program to check what is_lock_free() returns for an arbitrary atomic-pointer. So here's the code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

bool isLockFreeAtomic( atomic<uint64_t> *a64 )
{
    return a64->is_lock_free();
}
```

And this is the disassembly of isLockFreeAtomic

```
|?isLockFreeAtomic@@YA_NPAU?$atomic@_K@std@@@Z| PROC
    movs        r0,#1
    bx          lr
ENDP
```

This is just `returns true`, aka `1`.

This implementation chooses to use `alignof( atomic<int64_t> ) == 8` so every `atomic<int64_t>` is correctly aligned.  This avoids the need for runtime alignment checks on every load and store.

(Editor's note: this is common; most real-life C++ implementations work this way.  This is why `std::is_always_lock_free` is so useful: because it's usually true for types where `is_lock_free()` is ever true.)

Comment: Yes, most implementations choose to give `atomic<uint64_t>` and `alignof() == 8` so they don't have to check alignment at runtime.  This old API gives them the option of not doing so, but on current HW it makes much more sense just to require alignment (otherwise UB, e.g. non-atomicity).  Even in 32-bit code where `int64_t` might only have 4-byte alignment, `atomic<int64_t>` requires 8-byte.  See [my comments on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816223/why-is-stdatomictis-lock-free-not-static-as-well-as-constexpr/58819817#comment103916969_58816304)

Comment: Put into different words: _If_ a compiler chooses to make `alignof` value for a fundamental type the same as the "good" alignment of the hardware, _then_ `is_lock_free` will always be `true` (and so will `is_always_lock_free`). Your compiler here does exactly this. But the API exists so other compilers can do different things.

Comment: You can be pretty sure that if the language says that unaligned access has undefined behaviour all atomics have to be properly aligned. No implementation will do any runtime-checks because of that.

Comment: @BonitaMontero Yes, but there is nothing in the language that forbids `alignof(std::atomic<double>) == 1` (so there would be no "unaligned access" in the C++ sense, hence no UB), even if the hardware can only guarantee lock-free atomic operations for `double`s on 4 or 8 byte boundaries. The compiler would then have to use locks in the unaligned cases (and return the appropriate boolean value from `is_lock_free`, depending on the memory location of the object instance).

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Yes, the non-static `std::atomic<>::is_lock_free()` API is designed to allow that implementation choice.  It would be a bad choice for real-world implementations so that's not how they actually work.  Calling it on a `std::atomic<>` object with less alignment than its `alignof` is already UB, so the fact that it still returns true is not a violation of anything, just means the API wasn't helpful for detecting that problem.

Answer (score 1):

`std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free()` may in some implementations return `true` or `false` depending on runtime conditions.

As pointed out by Peter Cordes in comments, the runtime conditions is not alignment, as atomic will (over-)align internal storage for efficient lock-free operations, and forcing misalignment is UB that may manifest as loss of atomicity.

It is possible to make an implementation that will not enforce alignment and would do runtime dispatch based on alignment, but it is not what a sane implementation would do. It only make sense to support  pre-C++17, if `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` is less than required atomic alignment, as overalignment for dynamic allocation does not work until C++17.

Another reason where runtime condition may determine atomicity is **runtime CPU dispatch**.

On x86-64, an implementation may detect the presence of `cmpxchg16b` via `cpuid` at initialization, and use it for 128-bit atomics, the same applies to `cmpxchg8b` and 64-bit atomic on 32-bit. If corresponding `cmpxchg` is not found, lock-free atomic is unimplementable, and the implementation uses locks.

MSVC doesn't do runtime CPU dispatch currently. It doesn't do it for 64-bit due to ABI compatibility reasons, and doesn't do it for 32-bit as already doesn't support CPUs without `cmpxchg8b`. Boost.Atomic doesn't do this by default (assumes `cmpxchg8b` and `cmpxhg16b` presence), but can be configured for the detection. I haven't bothered to look what other implementations do yet.

Comment: The non-static `std::atomic<>::is_lock_free()` API does *allow* the possibility of an implementation with `alignof(std::atomic<T>)` less than `sizeof`.  Current implementations *choose* to have alignof == sizeof so they don't need runtime alignment checks.  (That means it's UB to call `is_lock_free` or any other member function on a misaligned `atomic<T>` object, so it doesn't matter what the return value is.)  Anyway, that's an implementation choice, not a constraint of ISO C++11.  (A good an obvious implementation choice, though!)  Good point about runtime dispatch as another reason, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, corrected. On another thought I found a possible reason not to rely on alignment: before C++17 the alignment for `new` was fixed to `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` and could not be increased by `alignas`. I don't think that some implementation uses smaller allocation alignment than required for largest lock-free atomic, but it looks like a reason to provide standard way to deal with this.

Comment: Interesting point about `new`.  You could consider runtime alignment checks for the largest object size (especially if it required atomic RMW just to read) instead of just deciding it would be never lock_free, if `new` aligned less than that.  Not the case on any mainstream x86 implementation, e.g. I think MSVC aligns by 16 on x86-64 (and GNU/Linux certainly does), and everything aligns by at least 8 in 32-bit mode.  IDK what alignof(max_align_t) is on gcc for AArch64 / MIPS64 / PPC64.  I think AArch64 would have 16-byte atomics baseline without even needing `-march` options, but prob. 16B new

Comment: @PeterCordes, we know where to query this for many of the configurations https://godbolt.org/z/73z11c49e