# Can moving memory to 32 bit register be unaligned access in NASM sometimes?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-alignment

I wonder if it is unaligned access in code like this:

```
section .text
 global _start
_start:
        mov eax, [arr + 1]

section .data
arr: db 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

Comment: What do you mean about whether is "can be"? Are you asking about if it's allowed, or if it can take place?

Comment: That would appear to be unaligned.

Comment: Yes, of course, for the same reason that `mov word [arr], imm16` is an aligned store if you build normally, like I explained in your last question about this.  [Is there unaligned access problem in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67305522)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical section alignment is 1000h, at least in PortableExecutables. When your program is linked and loaded to memory, the virtual address of `section .data` will be aligned, so the first data `arr` is aligned as well.

Loading a register from address `mov eax, [arr + 1]` is unaligned, of course, but it will work anyway, though not as fast as `mov eax, [arr]` would do.

Comment: It is just as fast on recent Intel/AMD cores, as long as it is <= 32 bits and the access doesn't cross a cache-line boundary.   It won't in the OP's sample.

Comment: @HansPassant: Since Nehalem for Intel (and recent AMD), there's no perf penalty for any access size as long as you don't have a cache-line split.  So on Skylake (or Zen 2), `vaddps ymm1, ymm0, [rdi + 30]` (32-byte load across the middle of one cache line, assuming RDI is aligned by 64) has no downside.  Some earlier AMD I think had some kind of performance effects at narrower boundaries like 16 or 32 byte.  (And/or non-atomicity for stores that spanned a 16-byte boundary within a cache line, while Intel did guarantee atomicity for 8-byte load/store within a cache lien.)